# Prove that $\operatorname{rad}R=\operatorname{Nil}(R)$ for $R=k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $R=k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$, where $I$ is an ideal in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $k$ is a field, Lam uses [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) to show that $\operatorname{rad}R=\operatorname{Nil}(R)$, but I can't seem to apply the wikipedia (applied to $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$) definition of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to show that $\sqrt{I}$ coincides with the intersection of maximal ideals of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ containing $I$. Further, how does it follow from that $\operatorname{rad}R=\operatorname{Nil}R$ is very unclear to me. If some can fill the gaps, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Nilradical of $R$ equals $\sqrt I/I$. If you know that $\sqrt I$ is the intersection of maximal ideals containing $I$, then you have proved that the Jacobson radical and the nilradical of $R$ are the same.

Comment: @user26857 Can you please expand your comment (i.e. why Nilrad(R) = $\sqrt I/I$) as an answer. I am not sure why $\sqrt I$ is the intersection of maximal ideals containing $I$.

Comment: In general, $N(A/I)=\sqrt I/I$. This is easily seen: if $\hat a\in A/I$ is nilpotent, then $\hat a^n=\hat 0$, that is, $a^n\in I$. The converse should be clear now.

Comment: $\sqrt I$ equals the intersection of maximal ideals containing $I$ is a result specific to the polynomial rings over fields since they are Jacobson/Hilbert rings. (Check the Wiki page dedicated to this class of rings.)